# element.appendChild() как выполнить действие после вставки элемента, есть ли коллбек?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Мне нужно программно сформировать iframe на странице и потом отправить в него postMessage. На момент отправки сообщения элемент ещё не отрисовался.
Может быть у appendChild есть какой-то коллбек в который можно добавить нужный мне функционал? Либо есть какие-то другие варианты? Только не setTimeout. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendChild` синхронная операция, скорее всего проблема в том, что фрейм не загрузился. Дожидайтесь события `onload` у фрейма

```
const frame = /* как то получили/создали фрейм */
frame.onload = function () {
  /* отправляем запрос */
}
document.body.appendChild(frame);
```

Comment: onload - точно же! Как сам не подумал об этом. Спасибо